# How to execute ajax fn in chain

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can be executed the two ajax fn `firstAjax()   &   secondAjax()` if
1. `firstAjax()` must execute before   `secondAjax()`
2. `secondAjax()` executes only after execution of `firstAjax()`.

***doesn't work***

```
$('#btn').click(function(){

     firstAJAX(); 
     secondAjax();  /* it doesn't wait for the execution of firstAjax() */
 });
```

***often works correctly ***

```
  $('#btn').click(function(){
        firstAJAX(); 
              alert("hello");  
         secondAjax();  /* it often works */
     });
```

Is there any other way to solve and make sure about the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You must wait for the firstAjax call to finish. If you are using jQuery to make the call then you can configure your ajax function like this:

```
function firstAJAX(args,callback,scope){
     // return the xhr Object used for this call, maybe you need it, if not, don't use return
     return $.ajax({
         url : "yourURL",
         success : function(){
         // this get's executed AFTER a SUCCESSFUL ajax call
              callback.call(scope || window);
         }
     });   
}
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for more information.

So, let's recap:

1) Ajax functions can have a/some callback/s (already implemented in jQuery)

2) You can hook the second request as a callback to the first.

Example:

```
firstAJAX(myArguments,secondAjax);
```

This will execute the firstAJAX function, that should look like the code I wrote before, and the secondAjax function should do the second request. Like this they are chained.

Comment: My pleasure :). The ajax method is quite full of options and callbacks, it's worth checking out!

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer this way :

```
function firstAJAX(){

  // done with first 
  secondAjax();
 }
```

I works fine if you put your secondAjax function after success(callback of your firstAjax function) of your firstAjax (not at the end of firstAjax function line)

Comment: this will only work, if the code that is symbolized by your comment `done with first` is synchronous. when it calls an ajax-request, this will be handled asynchronously and the function `secondAjax` will not necessarily be called after the ajax-call has finished.

Comment: @Chips_100 then on try to place secondAjax() function on success of firstAjax

Comment: @Tushar Ahirrao : no, it's not working for me. i have tried this already.

Comment: @user744587.. I works fine if you put your secondAjax function after success(callback of your firstAjax function) of your firstAjax (not at the end of firstAjax function line)

Answer (score 0):

The keyword to this is `callback` Functions. In Your `firstAJAX()` function, you will somewhere have the possibility to pass a callback-function, that will be executed, when that ajax-request has finished.
Either google for terms `ajax` and `callback` or post your code inside of the functions `firstAjax` and `secondAjax` so we can help you better.

Comment: Thanks Chips_100.. ! Code are very lengthy that's why i just posted in few lines. BTW i got yur logic, let me try first.